# Hamming distance to primes

Tags: nt.number-theory, prime-numbers, coding-theory

There is a positive density of odd numbers which are of the form $2^n+p$ (due to Romanoff), and a positive density which are not of this form (due to van der Corput and Erdos, see [this paper](https://doi.org/10.1090/mcom/3537) for a review and some results on the density). So, for some but not almost all odd numbers, we can get to a prime by subtracting a power of two.

I'm curious about a related question: given an odd integer $m$, is there always a prime number with Hamming distance 1 to $m$? For example, $127 = 1111111_2$ is not of the form $2^n+p$, but it has Hamming distance 1 to a prime, since $383 = 101111111_2$ is prime.

A related question, which implies the first: given an odd integer $m$, does the set $\{m+2^n\mid n\in \mathbb{N}\}$ contain infinitely many primes (or at least one for which $2^n>m$, so that this corresponds to flipping a bit in $m$)?

Comment: The sum from $n$ to infinity of the one over the log of $2^n+m$ is infinite, but I can't imagine trying to prove the existence of such primes with current technology. Even getting density 1 seems impossible to me - you would need to look to $n$ exponentially large in $m$.

Comment: The sequence "least prime with Hamming distance 1 from the k'th odd integer" starts
$3, 2, 7, 3, 11, 3, 5, 7, 19, 3, 5, 7, 17, \ldots$.  It doesn't seem to be in the [OEIS](https://oeis.org) yet, but should be.  Are you interested in contributing it?  If you don't wish to, I can (with a link to this question).

Comment: Thanks very much for your answer, I wasn't aware of the (dual) Sierpiński numbers. I'll go ahead and add this to the OEIS.

Comment: I think this question has already been asked in a slightly different form and answered here: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/316867/is-there-a-2-power-twinless-prime

Answer (score 24, accepted):

See OEIS sequences [A067760](https://oeis.org/A067760) and [A076336](https://oeis.org/A076336). If $n$ is a dual Sierpiński number, there is no $k$ such that $n+2^k$ is prime. There is no prime with Hamming distance $1$ to the Sierpiński number $2131099$, and this may be the least positive integer with this property.